# Confusion about Camunda tasks vs. activities

Tags: camunda

In the latest Camunda doc pages, I noticed some confusing information in a section that talks about listeners for tasks vs. listeners for activities: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-applications/process-application-event-listeners/ .

For instance, this section has the following text (my bolding of two words):

> The invoice process has a **task** named “archive invoice”. The application “invoice.war” further provides a Java Class implementing the ExecutionListener interface and is configured to be invoked whenever the END event is fired on the “archive invoice” **activity**.

I know that giving names to abstract terms is fraught with difficulties, but it sure seems like this text is not being clear on what's a "task" vs. an "activity".

Answer (score 5):

This question was already answered by Thorben and me in the Camunda forum.

See my answer [here](https://forum.camunda.org/t/i-like-to-know-the-difference-of-activity-and-task/1307/3?u=zelldon):

> An activity is the global class on which tasks, subprocess, call
>   activities etc. belongs to. So a Task is also an activity, but an
>   activity is not necessarily a task. See the [reference](https://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/) for more
>   detailed explanation.

And Thorbens [addition](https://forum.camunda.org/t/i-like-to-know-the-difference-of-activity-and-task/1307/4?u=zelldon):

> In addition to Chris' explanation, the term task is overloaded in the
>   Camunda and BPMN context. It refers to a task in the BPMN 2.0 context
>   (aka a design time unit of work that is/cannot broken down further =>
>   service task, human task, send task, etc.) as well as a task in the
>   tasklist (aka a runtime unit of work that needs to be completed by a
>   human).

Hope it helps.